# Spring boot MVC : Whitelabel Error Page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Getting the following Whitelabel Error Page while
I am running Spring Boot MVC app.

Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Apr 13 15:45:59 IST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Circular view path [home]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/rewards/web/home] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)

**application.properties**

```
server.contextPath=/rewards/web
```

**rewardsweb-servlet.xml:**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.rewards.web" />

    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <display-name>rewards-web</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>  
   <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>  
  </welcome-file-list>  
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>rewardsweb</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
                    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
                </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>rewardsweb</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Spring Boot files

```
package com.rewards.web;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;


@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}

package com.rewards.web;

import io.undertow.Undertow.Builder;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.undertow.UndertowBuilderCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.undertow.UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class ApplicationConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory embeddedServletContainerFactory() {
        UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new UndertowEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
        factory.addBuilderCustomizers(new UndertowBuilderCustomizer() {

            public void customize(Builder builder) {
                builder.addHttpListener(9090, "0.0.0.0");
            }

        });
        return factory;
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
package com.rewards.web.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String getHome(){
        System.out.println("-------this is home----------");
        return "home";
    }
}
```

**JSP**

```
home.jsp is in this path : /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/views/jsp/home.jsp
```

when i hit : **http://localhost:9090/rewards/web/home**
i am getting Whitelabel Error

And also i have tried following solution,  added the following code in controller class. but no help.

```
package com.rewards.web.controller;

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorController;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController implements ErrorController{

    private static final String PATH = "/error";

    @RequestMapping(value = PATH)
    public String error() {
        return "Error handling";
    }

    public String getErrorPath() {
        return PATH;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public String getHome(){
        System.out.println("-------this is home----------");
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Can you please help me out. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is NO **web.xml** in Spring Boot.

All of your above xml configuration is ignored by Spring Boot. Spring Boot uses Java Config (although you can use configuration from xml, but you shouldn't use xml for new projects).

This is how you define `InternalResourceViewResolver` in Spring Boot:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class ApplicationWebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
}
```

Here is [Spring Boot JSP Demo App](https://github.com/RawSanj/SOFRepos/tree/master/Spring-Boot-Jsp-Demo) which will help you modify your Project to actually make it Spring Boot project.

Also I suggest you to go through this [Spring Boot Guide](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) for getting started with Spring Boot WebApp and the [Spring Boot Reference Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a Dispatcher Servlet. Maybe something like this:

Dispatcher Config:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Application Config

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, but it turned out to be not Spring Boot's problem.
If you have frontend in Angular 2+, try using

```
{
  provide: LocationStrategy,
  useClass: HashLocationStrategy
}
```

in your app.module.ts and it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow below thing steps before rendering a JSP page in spring boot application.

1.application.properties

spring.mvc.view.prefix = /*
spring.mvc.view.suffix = .jsp

2.POM.XML

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
   <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

3.Place JSPs in proper path. I prefer below folder structure -> src\main\webapp\view\

If you follow above points,JSP will happily integrated with springboot